# io.Copy fails to copy all data to http.ResponseWriter

Tags: http, go, amazon-s3, streaming

In the following codes, `s.getFile` gets file from S3 and return a struct of `io.ReadCloser` and `ContentLength`.
`WriteResultesponse` write the file to `http.ResponseWriter`.

But `*reader.ContentLength` sometimes is different from `actualContentLength`.

Any idea why? Thanks

```
s3Ctx, closeS3 := context.WithTimeout(ctx, xxx) // 1 hour
defer closeS3()
// directly stream result from locations
for _, location := range Locations {
    reader, err := s.getFile(s3Ctx, xxx)
    // reader is 
    //struct {
    //    Data          io.ReadCloser
    //    ContentLength *int64
    //}
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    actualContentLength, err := WriteResultesponse(params.Writer, ResultResponse{
        Data:        reader.Data,
    })
}


// WriteResultResponse streams the result data to the user.
func WriteResultResponse(w http.ResponseWriter, resultResp ResultResponse) (int64, error) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/plain")
    // resultResp.Data is io.ReadCloser
    defer resultResp.Data.Close()
    return io.Copy(w, resultResp.Data)
}
```

**UPDATE**

How about

```
    if f, ok := params.Writer.(http.Flusher); ok {
        f.Flush()
    }
```

?

Comment: You are using a context with timeout. Maybe it is timing out during the copy operation?

Comment: @BurakSerdar the timeout is 1 hour

Comment: Which figure (`*reader.ContentLength`/`actualContentLength`/neither) is correct? (you have not shown how `ContentLength` is calculated).

Comment: Re your update - I don't understand how that might help. Calling `Flush` will flush buffered data to the client; that is not going to change the value already returned from the call to `io.Copy`.

Comment: @Brits you are right. 

I guess it may be because of `defer resultResp.Data.Close()`

I am not sure

Comment: @BAE I can't see how (that will run after the copy). Currently I'm still not sure what the problem is; I get that the two numbers don't match but are you sure that `*reader.ContentLength` is correct? Without some knowledge of the data you are dealing with its not really possible to help at the moment (the code shown looks OK).

Comment: @Brits yes, I am sure *reader.ContentLength is right. I downloaded the file from s3. the size is right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235960/discussion-between-brits-and-bae).